# Oracle Spatial-Extracting Individual Rings in a MultiPolygon

Tags: ruby, spatial, oracle-spatial

In a multipolygon,I need to count how many rings the polygon has,and then individually extract the rings and it's coordinates

Comment: And what have you tried so far? How does your code look and work?

Comment: @Emz I have used the sdo_util.extract(),but i have unknown number of elements and rings.I am new to Oracle spatial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First, You need to use a function for getting inner polygon count.

```
    create or replace
Function GetNumRings( p_geometry  in mdsys.sdo_geometry,
                      p_ring_type in integer default 0 /* 0 = ALL; 1 = OUTER; 2 = INNER */ )
  Return Number
Is
   v_ring_count number := 0;
   v_ring_type  number := p_ring_type;
   v_elements   number;
   v_etype      pls_integer;
Begin
   If ( p_geometry is null ) Then
      return 0;
   End If;
   If ( p_geometry.sdo_elem_info is null ) Then
      return 0;
   End If;
   If ( v_ring_type not in (0,1,2) ) Then
      v_ring_type := 0;
   End If;
   v_elements := ( ( p_geometry.sdo_elem_info.COUNT / 3 ) - 1 );
   <<element_extraction>>
   for v_i IN 0 .. v_elements LOOP
     v_etype := p_geometry.sdo_elem_info(v_i * 3 + 2);
     If  ( v_etype in (1003,1005,2003,2005) and 0 = v_ring_type )
      OR ( v_etype in (1003,1005)           and 1 = v_ring_type )
      OR ( v_etype in (2003,2005)           and 2 = v_ring_type ) Then
         v_ring_count := v_ring_count + 1;
     end If;
   end loop element_extraction;
   Return v_ring_count;
End GetNumRings;
```

Ref: [GetNumRings Function for Oracle-Spatial](http://spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/203/alternative-to-my-sql-based-getnumrings-function)

### Then, with this count you will get inner polygons

```
 FOR i IN 2..countFromFunction
    LOOP            
        begin
         insert into target_table(geom) 
          select SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT(t.geom,1,i) FROM source_table t;
          exception when others then 
          continue;
          end;
   end loop;
```

Loop is started from 2, because 1 will get outer ring.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It did help. Thank You. :-)

Comment: You don't need to write your own function to extract the number of elements, that's what SDO_UTIL.GETNUMELEM is for. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_util.htm#BJEEEJGH

Answer (score 2):

To be complete: `SDO_UTIL.GETNUMELEM()` returns the number of elements in a polygon, where an element is defined as being an outer ring with all its inner rings. `SDO_UTIL.GETNUMRINGS()` will give the total number of rings in the polygon (outer and inner rings).

For example, consider a shape that represents an archipelago of three islands, and each island has two lakes. That would be a multipolygon with **three elements**, each one containing two holes: GETNUMELEM will return 3, GETNUMRINGS returns 9 (3 outer rings and 6 inner rings).

So you need to be **clearer about your need**. If you want to split that archipelago into the three individual islands (each with its two internal lakes), then you can do as suggested in the first answer. Something like this:

```
create or replace procedure split_geom (geom sdo_geometry)
as
begin
  for i in 1..sdo_util.getnumelem(geom) loop            
    insert into target_table(element_id, geom) 
    values (i, sdo_util.extract(geom,i));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

On the other hand, if you want to split the entire shape into individual rings (i.e. also separate out the voids), then try this:

```
create or replace procedure split_geom (geom sdo_geometry)
as
  element sdo_geometry;
begin
  for i in 1..sdo_util.getnumelem(geom) loop
    -- Extract element (with its inner rings)
    element := sdo_util.extract(geom,i); 
    for j in 1..sdo_util.getnumelem(element) loop 
      -- Extract ring        
      insert into target_table(element_id, ring_id, geom) 
      values (i, j, sdo_util.extract(element,1,j));
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Note that when an inner ring is extracted from a polygon, it is returned as a valid single element, single ring polygon, with its ordinates re-oriented to counter-clockwise.

Comment: Archipelago example is very useful!

Comment: In the inner loop sdo_util.getnumrings(element) worked for me i.e: for j in 1..sdo_util.getnumrings(element) loop

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `SDO_UTIL.GETNUMELEM` to work out the number of elements in a polygon or multipolygon.
2. Extract each element with `SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT`, bearing in mind that the first element will be an outer boundary.